# My.User.IsAuthenticated bug in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, authentication, forms-authentication, genericprincipal

I don't know exactly how to explain it, but here is basically how my problem could be reproduced:

- Create a WPF Windows Application Project in VB.NET (don't create, just keep reading this, unless you don't believe me...)
- Click the Window's header to create a Window.Loaded event-handler and to navigate to it.
- Add the following to the event-handler:
  `My.User.CurrentPrincipal = New GenericPrincipal( _

  New GenericIdentity("username"), Nothing)

  Dim authenticated = My.User.CurrentPrincipal.IsAuthenticated

  MessageBox.Show(authenticated) 'True'`
- Go back to the window designer and add a Button to the Window1.
- Click the Button to create its Click event-handler and navigate to it.
- Add the following content to it:
  `Dim authenticated = My.User.CurrentPrincipal.IsAuthenticated

  MessageBox.Show(authenticated) 'False'`
- Run the application, see the results
- WHY ON THE EARTH IS IT FALSE NOW!?!?

**UPDATE:** I reported a bug at: http://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=513731, please vote or post a workaround, and update me when you do so, thanks in advance.

Any workarounds will be welcommed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping to find a definitive explanation for this behavior, but no such luck (yet). I do think I can offer you a work-around, though, which is to assign the custom principal object via AppDomain.SetThreadPrincipal (typically AppDomain.**CurrentDomain.**SetThreadPrincipal).

**EDIT:**

It turns out someone brought up this issue on the MSDN Forums. The [discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/67bada95-2d3d-40fd-94e3-b910c1d823ef) documents the work-around I already referenced, along with an explanation of the behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a good workaround!
Please go to that link in my querstion, vote and click "I can reproduce".